# How to add click event or link an HTML5 Canvas object?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I've been looking for solution but unable to find one.

This is the link i am referring
http://swingpants.com/2011/11/02/creative-javascript-3d-tree-with-leaf-fall/

I want to add click event on the tree leaf intention is to links the leafs something like

Answer (score 0):

You can not add event listeners to what is drawn on Canvas. You can listen to Canvas click events and then manually find the leaf at click location.